# How to create a weekly time-series from a daily data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have below data table which is at daily level (not regular gaps between data points) which I want to convert into weekly level (starting from a given date and rolling data every 7 days) in python. Data table looks like below:

```
ID Date Value
1  8/9/2018 2857
1  8/15/2018 2194
1  8/23/2018 226
1  8/30/2018 685
-     ----    --
2  8/6/2018 1390
2  8/17/2018 1162
2  8/27/2018 6320
2  8/30/2018 1150
```

Output required is below:

```
Data rolling starts from 1st Jul'2018

ID       Period             Value
1  8/1/2018-8/7/2018          0
1  8/8/2018-8/14/2018        2857
1  8/15/2018-8/21/2018       2194
-   ----------------          --
2  8/1/2018-8/7/2018         1390
2  8/8/2018-8/14/2018         0
2  8/15/2018-8/21/2018       1162
-   ----------------          -
 till 31st Jul'2020.
```

Comment: What if there are two or more dates? Sum?

Comment: Yes @irahorecka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you are grouping `Period` and `Value` (sum for same week) under the same `ID`. Hence, the solution won't work without grouping by `ID`.

For each month, as seen from your data, the split weeks is not to be started on any Sunday or Monday, but each week starts at 1st, 8th, 15, 22nd, 29th of the month.  Hence, we have to special tailor for such week ranges.

We can do it this way:

```
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['week_start'] = df['Date1'] - pd.to_timedelta((df['Date1'].dt.day - 1) % 7, unit='d')
df['week_finish'] = df['week_start'] + pd.Timedelta('6D')
df['Period'] = df['week_start'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').astype(str) + '-' + df['week_finish'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').astype(str)
df.groupby(['ID', 'week_start', 'Period'])['Value'].sum().reset_index([0,2]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

### Demo

**Test Data Construction**
As your sample data cannot test condition of summing up 2 entries of the same week, I have added new data with `ID` equals `3`, as follows:

```
data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
 'Date': ['8/9/2018',
  '8/15/2018',
  '8/23/2018',
  '8/30/2018',
  '8/6/2018',
  '8/17/2018',
  '8/27/2018',
  '8/30/2018',
  '8/6/2018',
  '8/7/2018',
  '8/27/2018',
  '8/28/2018'],
 'Value': [2857,
  2194,
  226,
  685,
  1390,
  1162,
  6320,
  1150,
  1000,
  2000,
  6320,
  1150]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

    ID       Date  Value
0    1   8/9/2018   2857
1    1  8/15/2018   2194
2    1  8/23/2018    226
3    1  8/30/2018    685
4    2   8/6/2018   1390
5    2  8/17/2018   1162
6    2  8/27/2018   6320
7    2  8/30/2018   1150
8    3   8/6/2018   1000
9    3   8/7/2018   2000
10   3  8/27/2018   6320
11   3  8/28/2018   1150
```

**Run New Codes**

```
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['week_start'] = df['Date1'] - pd.to_timedelta((df['Date1'].dt.day - 1) % 7, unit='d')
df['week_finish'] = df['week_start'] + pd.Timedelta('6D')
df['Period'] = df['week_start'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').astype(str) + '-' + df['week_finish'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').astype(str)
df.groupby(['ID', 'week_start', 'Period'])['Value'].sum().reset_index([0,2]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
   ID                 Period  Value
0   1  08/08/2018-08/14/2018   2857
1   1  08/15/2018-08/21/2018   2194
2   1  08/22/2018-08/28/2018    226
3   1  08/29/2018-09/04/2018    685
4   2  08/01/2018-08/07/2018   1390
5   2  08/15/2018-08/21/2018   1162
6   2  08/22/2018-08/28/2018   6320
7   2  08/29/2018-09/04/2018   1150
8   3  08/01/2018-08/07/2018   3000
9   3  08/22/2018-08/28/2018   7470
```

Note that the output is a little bit different from your desired output where every week, even without value, should still show 0 value.  To support this, the codes will be much more complicated.  You can already see the values grouped by ID and week in correct calendar order now (the sorting sequence of date is guaranteed by the interim field `week_start` which is in YYYY-MM-DD format so that the sorting sequence of chronological order is secured.  Sorting following `Period` order will result in same month of different years sorted together, defeating the chronological order.

### Edit

If the weeks are to be relative to `2018-08-01` instead of being the 1st day of each month, we can modify the line setting `df['week_start']`, as follows:

```
df['week_start'] = df['Date1'] - pd.to_timedelta((df['Date1'] - pd.Timestamp('2018-08-01')).dt.days % 7, unit='d')
```

### Test Run

`ID` equals `3` is now set to be in Sep 2018.

```
data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
 'Date': ['8/9/2018',
  '8/15/2018',
  '8/23/2018',
  '8/30/2018',
  '8/6/2018',
  '8/17/2018',
  '8/27/2018',
  '8/30/2018',
  '9/6/2018',
  '9/7/2018',
  '9/27/2018',
  '9/28/2018'],
 'Value': [2857,
  2194,
  226,
  685,
  1390,
  1162,
  6320,
  1150,
  1000,
  2000,
  6320,
  1150]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)


    ID       Date  Value
0    1   8/9/2018   2857
1    1  8/15/2018   2194
2    1  8/23/2018    226
3    1  8/30/2018    685
4    2   8/6/2018   1390
5    2  8/17/2018   1162
6    2  8/27/2018   6320
7    2  8/30/2018   1150
8    3   9/6/2018   1000
9    3   9/7/2018   2000
10   3  9/27/2018   6320
11   3  9/28/2018   1150
```

**Run New Codes:**

```
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['week_start'] = df['Date1'] - pd.to_timedelta((df['Date1'] - pd.Timestamp('2018-08-01')).dt.days % 7, unit='d')
df['week_finish'] = df['week_start'] + pd.Timedelta('6D')
df['Period'] = df['week_start'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').astype(str) + '-' + df['week_finish'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').astype(str)
df.groupby(['ID', 'week_start', 'Period'])['Value'].sum().reset_index([0,2]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
   ID                 Period  Value
0   1  08/08/2018-08/14/2018   2857
1   1  08/15/2018-08/21/2018   2194
2   1  08/22/2018-08/28/2018    226
3   1  08/29/2018-09/04/2018    685
4   2  08/01/2018-08/07/2018   1390
5   2  08/15/2018-08/21/2018   1162
6   2  08/22/2018-08/28/2018   6320
7   2  08/29/2018-09/04/2018   1150
8   3  09/05/2018-09/11/2018   3000
9   3  09/26/2018-10/02/2018   7470
```

Comment: One issue I am facing now...every month the period is starting from 1st...can we make it continuous i.e. the 7 days rolling period from earlier month can continue in next months.

Comment: @adi5257  I thought it was your intention for such format from your sample data which does not starts on either Monday or Sunday but on 1st of a month.  Anyway, what day of week you want a week to start ?   Start every Monday ?

Comment: I want the period to start from '2018-08-01' and then take data for every 7 days and group it till '2020-07-31'. The same needs to be done separately at ID level.

Comment: @adi5257  That's another special tailored-made week ranges.  Let me look at it and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is working exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def get_week(x,start_date):
    return ((x.date()-start_date.date()).days)//7

df['formatted_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
start_date = pd.to_datetime('Add your start date')

df["week"] = df["formatted_date"].apply(lambda x:get_week(x,start_date))
df["year"] = df.formatted_date.apply(lambda x: x.year)
    
df.groupby(['week','year']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use groupby() method. Make sure values are numeric (int, float not object)

```
        date  value
0 2018-08-09   2857
1 2018-08-15   2194
2 2018-08-23    226
3 2018-08-30    685
4 2018-08-06   1390
5 2018-08-17   1162
6 2018-08-27   6320
7 2018-08-30   1150
>>> df['week']=df['date'].transform(lambda x: x.week)
>>> df.groupby('week').sum()
      value
week       
32     4247
33     3356
34      226
35     8155
```